# Не могу вывести в поле значение выбранного пункта из списка

Tags: javascript, массивы

По нажатию на любой из списка элемент, хочу чтоб значение нажатого элемента списка отображалось в блоке, в моем случае отображает `underfiend`, хочу спросить почему так происходит, укажите на мою ошибку пожалуйста

```js
function func() {
  var sound = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  var a = [];
  for (i = 0; i < sound.length; i++) {
    a[i] += +sound[i].innerHTML;
  }
  document.getElementById('show_sound').innerHTML = a[i];
}
```

```css
.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ol class="list-item">
    <li onclick="func()">элемент списка 1</li>
    <li onclick="func()">элемент списка 2</li>
    <li onclick="func()">элемент списка 3</li>
    <li onclick="func()">элемент списка 4</li>
    <li onclick="func()">элемент списка 5</li>
    <li onclick="func()">элемент списка 6</li>
    <li onclick="func()">элемент списка 7</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="show_sound" class="sound">

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ещё один вариант - делегирование:

```js
document.querySelector('.list-item').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'LI') { document.querySelector('.sound').innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML; }
})
```

```css
.list-item li:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ol class="list-item">
    <li>элемент списка 1</li>
    <li>элемент списка 2</li>
    <li>элемент списка 3</li>
    <li>элемент списка 4</li>
    <li>элемент списка 5</li>
    <li>элемент списка 6</li>
    <li>элемент списка 7</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="show_sound" class="sound"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, сейчас же буду разбирать код, иначе я такого даже и близко не знал

Comment: скажите что это за "e" в функции function(e) откуда оно взялось?

Comment: @РоманРомашко `e` (может быть любое имя) - это параметр, который передаёт обработчик  `addEventListener`, как аргумент в функцию, а именно объект `event`, в котором, в свою очередь, содержится вся информация о событии - например, целевой элемент, на котором произошло событие.

Comment: @UModeL поздравляю с круглой цифрой и ответ на уровне

Answer (score 4):

Я бы так реализовал

```js
[...sound = document.getElementsByTagName('li')].forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('show_sound').innerHTML += s.innerHTML
  })
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ol class="list-item">
    <li>элемент списка 1</li>
    <li>элемент списка 2</li>
    <li>элемент списка 3</li>
    <li>элемент списка 4</li>
    <li>элемент списка 5</li>
    <li>элемент списка 6</li>
    <li>элемент списка 7</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="show_sound" class="sound">

</div>
```

Вариант два

```js
let a = [];
[...sound = document.getElementsByTagName('li')].forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    a.push(s.innerHTML);
    document.getElementById('show_sound').innerHTML = a

  })
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ol class="list-item">
    <li>элемент списка 1</li>
    <li>элемент списка 2</li>
    <li>элемент списка 3</li>
    <li>элемент списка 4</li>
    <li>элемент списка 5</li>
    <li>элемент списка 6</li>
    <li>элемент списка 7</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="show_sound" class="sound">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = [];
function func(i) {
 var sound = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    a = sound[i].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('show_sound').innerHTML = a;
}
```

```css
.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ol class="list-item">
    <li onclick="func(0)">элемент списка 1</li>
    <li onclick="func(1)">элемент списка 2</li>
    <li onclick="func(2)">элемент списка 3</li>
    <li onclick="func(3)">элемент списка 4</li>
    <li onclick="func(4)">элемент списка 5</li>
    <li onclick="func(5)">элемент списка 6</li>
    <li onclick="func(6)">элемент списка 7</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="show_sound" class="sound">
```

У вас много лишнего кода и куча ошибок
+sound[i].innerHTML- плюс в начале переобразовывает к числу
зачем вам массив a[]? если нужно выводить одно значение?
и в конце у вас выходит i = 7, а массив идет до a[6]